Azure web app service won't find my web app's manifest.json file
I have completed the development of a web application, everything works as intended when launched in localhost ( manifest and service worker included).
I am in the process of deploying the application using azure's app service for students.
the core functionalities of the application are correctly deployed (connection to database, page navigations user interaction etc.)
unfortunately the manifest file is not loaded correctly, and this error is logged in the dev tool's console:
"GET https://basketballlearningplatform.azurewebsites.net/manifest.json 404 (Not Found)"

so far coding wise I have have:

double checked that the manifest file is correctly linked in the layout.ejs head:

<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">


made sure that the public folder is correctly served in the app.js:

app.use(express.static("./public"));

NOTE: I don't think there is anything wrong with the implementation itself otherwise it wouldn't work in localhost either (correct me if I'm wrong)
Additionally I have checked that:

the manifest files is present in the azure vscode extension:

files in azure vscode extension

the manifest file is present in the KUDU debug console through the azure portal:

files in kudu debug console
thanks in advance to anyone that has the solution to this!

what does your azure app service log stream show?

well, it's a bit hard to explain in a comment.
but once I deploy the web app, both the "applications logs" in azure portal and the output terminal in VScode show a series of commands like this:
 2024-12-07 15:45:16 ~1BASKETBALLLEARNINGPLATFORM GET /api/deployments/temp-e032cb80/log X-ARR-LOG-ID=4bf2d1ee-fbe0-42b2-ba94-e2b96db366c4 443 - 86.5.103.53 vscode-azureappservice/0.25.4+core-rest-pipeline/1.16.3+Node/20.18.0+OS/(x64-Windows_NT-10.0.22631) - - basketballlearningplatform.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 929 1433 77
I hope this is what you were referring to

I created a sample application, successfully deployed the app to azure web app and can view the /manifest.json page.

The line app.use(express.static("./public")); expects the public folder to be at the main level of your project. Check that the public folder is in the correct location.

I've changed the line
app.use(express.static("./public")); to below and it worked for me
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

Make sure you add correct manifest.json file path in the code
app.get('/manifest.json', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/js/manifest.json'));
});


This line tells the app to send the manifest.json file located in the public/js/ folder as the response when a request is made to /manifest.json.

Complete app.js:
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const ejsLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');

const app = express();

app.use(ejsLayouts);

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/manifest.json', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/js/manifest.json'));
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

Successfully deployed the app to Azure web app
Output:


I haven't used any settings.py file in my project. The error you're facing might be related to packages or environment variables not being fetched correctly.
